# The map support Fragment Unfortunetely stopped

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

i use google map api v2 and i follow google tutorial and this logcat shows those errors:

```
04-30 09:13:35.687: E/Trace(1875): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-30 09:13:36.974: W/dalvikvm(1875): VFY: unable to resolve static field 875 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
04-30 09:13:36.974: D/dalvikvm(1875): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
04-30 09:13:37.034: D/AndroidRuntime(1875): Shutting down VM
04-30 09:13:37.034: W/dalvikvm(1875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.example.androidapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-30 09:13:37.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1875):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: hope you have imported google-play-services_lib and added that lib Project in your Project.

Comment: check your google-playservices-lib added to your project properly and Run your project in Actual device instead of emulator.

Comment: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-google-map-v2-part-1.html

Comment: i can't edit my question first time here :)

Comment: i'm already do this code and it is stopped

Comment: do you think those errors related to the emulator??!

Comment: error is related to google-play-services_lib import that Properly and use it in your Project. also use android-support-v4.jar and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Dhawal i'm Already do those steps and the same errors

Comment: i kno you have added this.. but just do all this step once again. i am sure you have miss one step...

Comment: Okay, I'll Try Once More Thanks

Comment: Dhawal it doesn't work this is my code:
http://www.4shared.com/rar/Q4GgCj-H/OnceMore.html?